# How do you make a method to save space?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void login() {
    if (driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"name\"]")).size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("true, element found, logging in");
        WebElement loginform = driver.findElement(By.name("name"));
        WebElement passwordform = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
        loginform.sendKeys("fhfghgfgh");
        passwordform.sendKeys("dgfgdfgdfdgf");
        driver.findElement(By.className("default__button")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"page\"]/div[1]/div/div[1 ]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("*[class^='default__button'")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

I have the above method in my java class three times. I wanted to save time and effort and just call on "login();" to save time.

However, when that code is taken out of the class and is in a vacuum, it turns into errors because it doesn't understand what the variables are anymore.

Is there anyway to just quote code into a method to be executed later?

Comment: what's to stop you from passing the variables values as parameters?

Comment: Even if it is, it would be a nighmare to debug and maintain. You'd better rethink your design instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's a static method. That sounds like a mistake, but if you intended to be, that does make it easier:

```
public class OneOfThoseClasses {
    public static void login() {
        OneOfTheOthers.login();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do login directly by hitting login API from your code without any UI interaction. That will save your time for sure.

Happy Testing!